# Big Gaps Between HTML Elements in Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, spacing

I'm trying to create a 3 column grid for one of the pages on my website. Some of the elements span 2 columns while others only span 1 column. This has created a spacing issue for me as I'd like the elements to kind of "float" up to the closest element above it to minimize the amount of gaps and trapped white space. For example, here is a very simple rendition of what the page looks like now:

[image]

and here is what I'd like it to look like:

[image]

[You can check out the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jb7bp57c/1/)

Here is the CSS:

```
*{
    color: white;
}

.clear{
clear:both;
}

.out_wrap_blk {
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.out_wrap_gry {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #323232;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.in_wrap_grn {
    border: 1px solid #0CFF0E;
    padding: 20px;
}
.in_wrap_blk {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
.col_1 {
    width: 298px;
}
.col_2 {
    width: 668px;
}
.col_3 {
    width: 1038px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="page_wrap">
    <div id="page_head">
        <div class="out_wrap_blk">
            <div class="in_wrap_grn col_3">
                 <h1>Test!!!</h1>
Bacon ipsum dolor amet chicken drumstick spare ribs t-bone leberkas brisket pork chop bacon beef ribeye pastrami. Tail bresaola pork andouille cow doner. Kevin short loin turducken picanha swine. Fatback prosciutto shank filet mignon short ribs capicola biltong pork loin landjaeger sausage beef meatball.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_gry">
        <div class="in_wrap_blk col_2">Andouille doner beef pancetta picanha tenderloin. Boudin picanha ham hock, ham brisket pancetta tongue beef ribs kevin swine.
            <br>Ham hock shank tongue pastrami turkey frankfurter. Strip steak pork filet mignon andouille ground round shoulder biltong jowl fatback short ribs pork belly cupim pig. Ground round venison cupim swine cow, jowl chuck tenderloin ham hock tongue jerky. Tail fatback pork loin pig. Tongue frankfurter leberkas kielbasa, hamburger strip steak bacon pork loin chuck biltong meatloaf venison picanha.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Turducken pork ball tip frankfurter tongue chicken sirloin sausage rump. Picanha turkey doner porchetta biltong kevin. Pastrami meatloaf pork belly, shoulder kevin jowl strip steak boudin. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">T-bone strip steak short ribs meatloaf tail swine ribeye flank pancetta tongue filet mignon rump sirloin. Kielbasa pork loin frankfurter sirloin brisket cow pork shank shankle swine corned beef meatloaf pig bacon. Alcatra beef ribs shankle tail, meatball corned beef pork chop jerky short ribs tongue porchetta fatback landjaeger.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_2">Filet mignon chicken pork chop, landjaeger flank tail ball tip hamburger.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Chuck short ribs porchetta ball tip pork belly brisket jerky doner ribeye sirloin tenderloin pork andouille pancetta. Prosciutto biltong salami meatloaf spare ribs pork belly short loin corned beef shoulder ribeye pig landjaeger tongue. Venison swine spare ribs beef.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Ribeye biltong fatback, capicola short loin ball tip kevin pork loin shankle salami meatball pork bresaola beef meatloaf. Pig short ribs tenderloin, cupim bresaola kevin fatback shoulder cow chicken jowl.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Capicola meatloaf tri-tip beef tongue. Tenderloin picanha andouille flank beef ribs swine, pork loin filet mignon pork chuck. Prosciutto filet mignon venison ham, shankle chuck kevin bresaola frankfurter. Ribeye jowl beef kevin prosciutto turducken picanha sausage drumstick jerky kielbasa tongue meatloaf turkey. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Shoulder pork chop chuck, beef ribs pork fatback shank prosciutto tail porchetta.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out_wrap_blk">
        <div class="in_wrap_grn col_1">Bacon sausage frankfurter landjaeger ham pig pancetta tongue rump turducken. Salami shank sausage meatloaf, ball tip landjaeger short ribs boudin pork loin turducken jerky meatball ham hock sirloin prosciutto. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this and eliminate those extra spaces?

Comment: Is this the layout you want always, or should the divs expand to new content, and thus their sizes will be different from time to time?

Comment: The layout will be static for now. The content inside the divs wont change. But eventually I'd like to make this page responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I would explain rather than just post a solution. But in this case there is too much to explain through typing. The basics are: You set your wrapper to a `max-width` so the layout doesn't get too large, but will shrink when made smaller. Then you need to break this out into columns. Two that wrap the left and right side, and then two more that wrap the smaller columns below the larger box:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="box large"></div>
        <div class="sub-column1">
            <div class="box small"></div>
            <div class="box large"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-column2">
            <div class="box large"></div>
            <div class="box small"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        <div class="box small"></div>
        <div class="box large"></div>
        <div class="box large"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    max-width: 500px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.column1{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.column2{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.sub-column1, .sub-column2{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sub-column2{
    padding: 0;
}

.box{
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.large{
    height: 100px;
}

.small{
    height: 15px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jb7bp57c/4/)

Comment: @DigitalBrent you got it. Glad to help.